# API call to Checkmarx dashboard

Tags: python, shell, api, checkmarx

I want to get all the Checkmarx scan details of all the project on Checkmarx dashboard page. How do I do this using the Checkmarx API called from shell or python script?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :  Get Report(s) by Id - GET /reports/sastScan/{id}

https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KC/pages/222101925/Get+Report+s+by+Id+-+GET+reports+sastScan+id+v8.6.0+and+up

Comment: Thanks. How I can call these API in my shell script. 
I tried running it using curl command but it's falling.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the curl command generated by swagger.
To access a live Swagger environment navigate to:

http://:/cxrestapi/help/swagger/ui/index (e.g.http://localhost/cxrestapi/help/swagger/ui/index)

If you want to use python scripts, you can try my demo on GitHub(https://github.com/binqsoft/CxRestPy)